# how to extract data inside a specific td in html table using java

Tags: java, html, href, html-table

I have:

```
<table class="cast_list">    
<tr><td colspan="4" class="castlist_label"></td></tr>
  <tr class="odd">
         <td class="primary_photo">
 <a href="/name/nm0000209/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_i1" ><img height="44" width="32" alt="Tim Robbins" title="Tim Robbins"src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/G/01/imdb/images/nopicture/32x44/name-2138558783._V379389446_.png"class="loadlate hidden " loadlate="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTI1OTYxNzAxOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNTE5ODI4._V1_SY44_CR1,0,32,44_AL_.jpg" /></a>          </td>
         <td class="itemprop" itemprop="actor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
 <a href="/name/nm0000209/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t1" itemprop='url'> <span class="itemprop" itemprop="name">Tim Robbins</span>
 </a>          </td>
           <td class="ellipsis">
                 ...
           </td>
```

how can I get only the information inside the second td class? (td class= itemprop). I want to get "/name/nm0000209/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t1" and "Tim Robbins".

This is my code:

```
Elements elms = doc.getElementsByClass("cast_list").first().getElementsByTag("table");
Elements tds = elms.select("td");
for(Element td : tds){
    if(td.attr("class").contains("itemprop")){
       Elements links = tds.select("a[href]");
       for(Element link : links){
           if(link.attr("href").contains("name/nm"))
         {
           String castname = link.text();
           String castImdbId = link.attr("href");
           System.out.println("CastName:" + castname + "\n");
           System.out.println("CastImdbID:" + castImdbId + "\n");
         }
```

but it also returns the text of the link inside td class="primary_phptp" which is null, this is part of my output:

CastName:

CastImdbID:/name/nm0000209/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_i1

CastName:Tim Robbins

CastImdbID:/name/nm0000209/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t1

CastName:

......

Could someone please let me know where is my problem? I think the condition if(td.attr("class").contains("itemprop")) does not work at all.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different css selector instead of `td`. Since the right `<td>` is identified be the class, why not use it:

```css
td.itemprop
```

Your java code then would start like this instead

```java
Elements tds = elms.select("td.itemprop");
```